# 'trying to overwrite file already in shotwell-common package' while installing shotwell from the PPA

Tags: dpkg

I am trying to update my version of Shotwell. Well, my Ubuntu system is. I am getting the following apt-get error. Can anyone tell me how to resolve it? I have tried a few different things so now asking for help.

```
root@nathanr-XPS-630i:/home/nathanr# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  shotwell
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 25.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yorba/ppa/ubuntu/ saucy/main shotwell i386 0.15.1-1~saucy1 [10.8 MB]
Fetched 10.8 MB in 2min 16s (79.5 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                
(Reading database ... 316303 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace shotwell 0.15.0-0ubuntu1 (using .../shotwell_0.15.1-1~saucy1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement shotwell ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/shotwell_0.15.1-1~saucy1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/shotwell.svg', which is also in package shotwell-common 0.15.0-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already                                                              Processing triggers for     software-center ...
INFO:softwarecenter.db.update:translation information in database is up-to-date
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/shotwell_0.15.1-1~saucy1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any suggestions what I need to do?

Comment: BTW, don't log in as root, use sudo instead

Answer (score 14):

Try this command on terminal,

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/shotwell_0.15.1-1~saucy1_i386.deb
```

This error occurs when some file was moved from one package to another in a newer version.

In your case `dpkg` trying to extract `shotwell.svg` file from `/var/cache/apt/archives/shotwell_0.15.1-1~saucy1_i386.deb` to `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/` directory.But there was already a `shotwell.svg` file in that directory.So this type of error occurs.

By running `dpkg -i --force-overwrite` command,the previously located file `shotwell.svg` was forcely overwrited by the file from the `/var/cache/apt/archives/shotwell_0.15.1-1~saucy1_i386.deb` while installing.

Here is the [source](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/fix-dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-x.html).

Comment: this solution worked for me only after I run this command:
sudo chmod 777 /var/cache/apt/archives/shotwell_0.15.1-1~saucy1_i386.deb

Comment: But for mine the above single command works.

Comment: you only need to add chmod command to make executable, that's will make your solution perfect, and it will work for everybody.

Comment: Did you try my another answer?

Comment: it tried your single command, and it failed until i used chmod

Comment: i mean this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/406415/202806.

Comment: No actually, since this solution works for me

Comment: Please go for dpkg --force option if all the other method fails.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i will do it next time i face similar issue

Answer (score 2):

Try these commands,

```
sudo dpkg -r shotwell-common
sudo apt-get install shotwell
```

`apt-get` may or may not work in this case of removing `shotwell-common` package.

Answer (score 1):

**You should report such things to the PPA owner.** He's not separating non-architecture specific files or setting that shotwell breaks/has conflicts with the shotwell-common package.

The correct way to do it is removing the repository shotwell-common package then installing the one from the ppa:

```
sudo apt-get purge shotwell-common
sudo apt-get install shotwell
```

This will prevent headaches while upgrading packages.

```
➜  ~  apt-cache policy shotwell-common
shotwell-common:
  Installed: 0.14.1-3
  Candidate: 0.14.1-3
  Version table:
 *** 0.14.1-3 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
➜  ~  sudo dpkg -i Downloads/shotwell*
[sudo] password for braiam: 
(Reading database ... 188756 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../shotwell_0.15.1-1~saucy1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking shotwell (0.15.1-1~saucy1) over (0.14.1-3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive Downloads/shotwell_0.15.1-1~saucy1_i386.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/shotwell.svg', which is also in package shotwell-common 0.14.1-3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 Downloads/shotwell_0.15.1-1~saucy1_i386.deb
➜  ~  sudo apt-get --reinstall install shotwell-common=0.14.1-3 shotwell=0.14.1-3       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,901 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main shotwell-common all 0.14.1-3 [1,965 kB]
Get:2 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main shotwell i386 0.14.1-3 [1,936 kB]
Fetched 3,901 kB in 24s (157 kB/s)                                             
(Reading database ... 188756 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../shotwell-common_0.14.1-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking shotwell-common (0.14.1-3) over (0.14.1-3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../shotwell_0.14.1-3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking shotwell (0.14.1-3) over (0.14.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.8.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.36.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.5-3) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46) ...
Setting up shotwell-common (0.14.1-3) ...
Setting up shotwell (0.14.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46) ...
➜  ~  sudo apt-get remove shotwell-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgee2 libgexiv2-2 libraw9
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  shotwell shotwell-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
After this operation, 12.1 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 188756 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing shotwell (0.14.1-3) ...
Removing shotwell-common (0.14.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.5-3) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.36.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.8.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54) ...
➜  ~  sudo dpkg -i Downloads/shotwell*.deb                      
Selecting previously unselected package shotwell.
(Reading database ... 188477 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../shotwell_0.15.1-1~saucy1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking shotwell (0.15.1-1~saucy1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.5-3) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.36.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.8.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46) ...
➜  ~
```

Comment: @Lionslair the correct way is marking the answer as accepted ;)